# Is it possible to use a comprehension list and index variable names?

Tags: variables, julia

Suppose that I want n variables `folder_i` such that:

`folder_i = "Some/path/example_$i"`

I believe you can have an array of `folder` like this:

```
folder = String[]
for i in 1:n
    folder[i] = "Some/path/example_$i"
end
```

But what if you want my variables to *have* `i` within their names? `folder_5`, `folder_9999` and so on?

I need this for a specific case of folders but it can be in general in Julia, having indexes naming variables.

Comment: The real answer is: _why_?